# ubuntu 14.04 как заменить php7 на php5

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, php7, php5

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста как заменить php 7 на php 5

Мои параметры:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

PHP Version 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
```

Мои действия:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Я уже пару раз сломал все это дело.
Подскажите пожалуйста шаги безболезненных действий чтоб это все работало с php5.6 версией.

Спасибо

Comment: не надо добавлять никаких левых репозиториев. в официальном репозитории [имеется пакет *php5*](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) (и производные). // примерный алогоритм: 1. уберите «левые» репозитории. 2. обновите список пакетов. 3. удалите всё связанное с php. 4. установите php5

Answer (score 1):

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`

не надо добавлять никаких «левых» репозиториев.

ведь в официальном репозитории [имеется пакет php5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) (и производные).

---

примерный алгоритм:

1. уберите «левые» репозитории (см. файлы в `/etc/apt/sources.d/`)
2. обновите список пакетов (`sudo apt-get update`)
3. удалите всё связанное с *php* (`sudo apt-get purge 'php.*'`)
4. установите пакет *php5* и необходимые дополнительные пакеты.